# Лексические нормы

Tags: грамотная-речь

Где в ниже перечисленных предложениях нарушены лексические нормы?

1. Дизайнеры начали оформление внутреннего интерьера ресторана.
2. Наши колошматили врагов везде: на воде, на земле, в воздухе.
3. Декада французской музыки продлится две недели.
4. Депутат не смог выполнить всех порученных ему вопросов.
5. Идёт снижение цен на товары первой необходимости.

Answer (score 1):

Недочеты разного рода есть во всех предложениях. 
1.ИНТЕРЬЕР — внутреннее пространство здания или отдельного помещения. Следовательно, внешнего не бывает. Слово "внутреннего" лишнее.
 2. Слово "колошматили" просторечное. Его уместно использовать в определённом контексте.
 3. Декада - это 10 дней.
 4. Никто не сможет выполнить вопросы. На них отвечают, в крайнем случае их решают.
5. Если не придираться к слову "идёт", то здесь всё верно.